# I've Downloaded and installed Ubuntu 20.04 and the OS is not loading

Tags: boot, virtualbox

Ive downloaded Ubuntu 20.4 and have successfully installed it onto Oracle VirtualBox, however after the installation is successfully I am presented with a restart option.

Once I restart the machine i am then presented with another screen with a message displaying ***'Please remove installation medium, and press ENTER'***

Once i press ENTER the machine then proceeds to try boot into the OS, this is where it has failed every time. I get the Message:

```
/dev/sda5: recovering journal
/dev/sda5: clean 201241/3244032 files, 2380744/12975360 Blocks
[     5.106954] [drm:vmw_host_log [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* Failed to send host log mesage.
[     5.106954] [drm:vmw_host_log [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* Failed to send host log mesage.
_
```

The screen will freeze here and not allow me to reboot orm ACPI shutdown the machine, I have to physically close the window and power down the machine.

I have tried altered the Video Memory from 16mb as default to the max amount of 128mb, i have tried disabling and enabling 3D acceleration as well as all the different Graphics Controllers.

I keep getting the same issue over and over,I'm not sure if i need to try older versions of UBUNTU.

Has anyone else faced a similar problem and can let me know of a fix?
I'm currently running:

```
Ryzen 5 2600x
16Gig 3200Mhz Ram
and a 500Gb ssd paired with a 1TB HDD
```

the graphic card installed is a AMD Radeon RX570 8GB (not that this matters)

looking for desperate help as i need to use this machine as a virtual lab and its starting to frustrate me.

I have attached some photos of the stuck screen and my VM Settings.

Thanks so much!

Stuck Screen

[image]

Settings

[image]

Comment: I'd suspect the installation ISO is bad; check the checksums.  If that doesn't help, check the vbox.log for the VM for clues.